# Solr 4.0 quering and filter by _version_

Tags: solr, solrj

I have an index which I update every few hours using Solrj.
The update contains new Docs and it also updates for excising Docs in index. Some won't be updated at all (consider as deleted after the update).

In each update I want to change the *version* field in all Docs that were updated.
currently i'm using:

```
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

The problem is that each Doc gets the unix time of its creation.
Is there a way to Auto-increment the *version* field for all new/updated Docs and also to filter the results in search query by latest *version*?

Answer (score 2):

Details about `_version_` field:

- `_version_` is used/controlled by Solr internally
- `_version_` field value automatically gets incremented, whenever any field value update happen to document. So only one updated document exists in the Index
- When search query issued, Solr returns updated document version by default

*This field is required when `Realtime` get handler and `updateLog` defined.*

I hope it explains and provides direction.

*Note: part references is not yet committed as per wiki*

If you like to deal explicitly with "part references", refer Solr wiki [Update Semantics](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Per%20Steffensen/Update%20semantics).

Comment: It should be noted that as of right now, the stuff on the "Update Semantics" link is not yet committed.